# how to pass the state property as prop to show and hide component in react when it's asynchronous update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a navbar when i click on it i'm setting my state to true and passing it in my component as  prop but the function takes time update it and my props are sent as false how can i send my updated prop when the state update is complete

navbar.js

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      burgerClicked:false,
    };
  }
 burgerClicked=()=>{
    this.setState({ burgerClicked: true },()=>{   this.props.clicked(this.state.burgerClicked)})
  }
```

app.js

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state={
      open:false,
     }
  }

 openSideNav =(burgerClicked)=>{// the time is taking here to update it send open as false 
     this.setState({open:burgerClicked},()=>{
       console.log(this.state.open)
     });

 <Navbar clicked={this.openSideNav} tokenRequested={this.request}/>
 <Header  open={this.state.open} />
```

header.js

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showSideNav: false };
  }


UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(){
    // 
    console.log(this.props.open,this.state.showSideNav);//this.props.open is false

    if (this.props.open) {
      this.setState({showSideNav:this.props.open},()=>{
        console.log(this.state.showSideNav); //this.state.showSideNav dont print on first click but print true on second click on burger

      })
    }

    console.log(this.props.open,this.state.showSideNav); //this.props.open is false
  }

   {(() => {
  if (!this.state.showSideNav) {
         return null;
        }
          return(
          <SideNavbar closeNav={this.closeSideNav}/>
           )
   })()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may be more than what you are asking for, but here it goes:

In this example you have three states: `burgerClicked` (in `Navbar.js`), `open` (in `App.js`), and `showSideNav` (in `header.js`).

It looks like all three of those keep track of the same thing: "is the side nav open?". You don't want that, you should have only one component that keeps track of that.

Based on your example, I would say that only `App.js` should have that state, and pass its value to `Navbar` and `header` as props.

In `Navbar.js`, the `onClick` just needs to call the `clicked` function, **without** passing any param. Then, `App.js` figures out whether to set `open` to `true` or `false`, (which most likely just means toggling it).

Once `App.js` updates its state, it will pass that updated value down to `header` and `Navbar` and that's the beauty of React.

Comment: it still gonna do it asynchronously

Comment: yeah, it will still be asynchronous, but React handles that asynchronousity (real word?) very well, and is a normal use case. Having the multiple states that need to stay in sync is not a normal React use case, and that asynchronousity will get things messy real quick.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is kinda not understandable and only can figure out you want to use conditional rendering.
Read this https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html
Hope it will help you :)